# Type error: Property 'isTV' does not exist on type 'PlatformStatic'. TS2339

Tags: typescript, react-native, react-native-ios

I have an application runs on TVOS with typescript integrated. To detect whether the device OS is TV or mobile I have used below the property and it works well without the webpack integration.

But after integrating the webpack and running on web I am facing the type errors like below,

`Type error: Property 'isTV' does not exist on type 'PlatformStatic'.  TS2339`

`Type error: Type '{ children: Element; activeOpacity: number; accessibilityLabel: string | undefined; accessibilityRole: "button"; accessibilityStates: AccessibilityState[]; onFocus: () => any; testID: string | undefined; disabled: boolean | undefined; onPress: () => any; }' is not assignable to type 'IntrinsicAttributes & IntrinsicClassAttributes<TouchableOpacity> & Readonly<{ children?: ReactNode; }> & Readonly<TouchableOpacityProps>'.
  Property 'onFocus' does not exist on type 'IntrinsicAttributes & IntrinsicClassAttributes<TouchableOpacity> & Readonly<{ children?: ReactNode; }> &
Readonly<TouchableOpacityProps>'.  TS2322`

It will be helpful If someone can explain why I am facing this error?

And how can I resolve this error?